# "Value cannot be null" while creating an XElement from the attributes where one or more value is null

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying out following code:

```
XElement element = new XElement("ENTS", from i in notificationsTracking
select new XElement("ENT", 
new object[] {
    new XAttribute("ENTID", i.TrackingID),
    new XAttribute("PID", i.Response?.NotificationProvider),
    new XAttribute("UID", i.Response?.NotificationUniqueId)
}));
```

This works fine when the response is not null, and there exists values in "NotificationProvider" or "NotificationUniqueId" fields. But in case if any of these three is null then I am getting an error saying - "Value cannot be null".

I know there is one solution wherein I can explicitly compare the object/ properties against Null/ Empty and can convert them accordingly, and that will work.

But is there any optimized or more efficient way to solve this issue?

Thanks and Regards,

Nirman

Comment: If you want to keep the attrib with an empty value `i.Response?.NotificationProvider ?? string.Empty`

Comment: How do you want to mark `PID` and `UID` of notifications with no `Response`?

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev - I simply want to ignore those attributes, in case if Response is null, or their respective properties are null/ empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with only a single null check (and you don't need the enclosing object[]):

```
XElement element = new XElement("ENTS", from i in notificationsTracking
select new XElement("ENT", 
    new XAttribute("ENTID", i.TrackingID),
    i.Response != null ? new [] {
        new XAttribute("PID", i.Response.NotificationProvider),
        new XAttribute("UID", i.Response.NotificationUniqueId),
        // more i.Response props ...
    } : null
));
```

Or if there are only two simply repeat the check:

```
XElement element = new XElement("ENTS", from i in notificationsTracking
select new XElement("ENT", 
    new XAttribute("ENTID", i.TrackingID),
    i.Response != null ? new XAttribute("PID", i.Response.NotificationProvider) : null,
    i.Response != null ? new XAttribute("UID", i.Response.NotificationUniqueId) : null
));
```